# I can send email from outside but not using phpmailer (error 111)

Tags: smtp, email-server, centos7

I can send email via my webserver from my computer (using Thunderbird), but not from my website using 'phpmailer'. Oddly enough, when I run 'telnet mail.myserver.com 25' on the server, it says 'connection refused', the same error message I'm getting with phpmailer (error 111 - "Connection refused"). However, emails are sent fine through Thunderbird (which is set up to port 25 also, only to use encrypted passwords), I can also connect with telnet just fine from my computer to the mail server.
Any idea what may be the reason for this strange problem? I'm using the latest phpmailer version, and the CentOS7 server is running php 5.6.18.

Output of netstat -an | grep 25:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Phpmailer config:

```
require_once("./stuff/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = $SMTPHOST;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Username = $SMTPUSER;    
$mail->setFrom($email,$name);
$mail->AddAddress($AdminMail);
$mail->Subject = "Here is the email";
$mail->Body = "I am an email";
if(!$mail->send()){..}
```

By the way, PHP's mail() method works also, only SMTP seems to cause the problem. So when I change $mail->IsSMTP() to $mail->IsMail(), it works.

Comment: add output of the 'netstat -an | grep 25 ' to the question

Comment: do you run `telnet mail.myserver.com 25` from mailserver itself or from remote server?

Comment: Could you add part of maillog file with error and phpmailer settings (server related) ?

Comment: @user1700494 from the server, it says 'connection refused' as well, from my local computer I can connect to postfix just fine.

Comment: Let me check DNS and firewall settings... When you issue `ping mail.myserver.com` from your computer and from the server, do both commands show the same IP? Do the output of commands `iptables -nvL` and `ip6tables -nvL` show that the firewall is disabled?

Comment: Pls clarify: do you able to connect to telnet port 25 from your local computer or do you able to send mails via t-bird from your local computer? Or both?

Comment: @user1700494 I'm both able to telnet and send emails from my local computer

Comment: @AndersonM.Gomes pinging is no problem, and from within the server it's the same IP as from outside. iptables -nvL gives  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
13839 5208K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   ; 
ipv6tables yields no output except the header lines.

Comment: Is there anything in /var/log/messages or /var/log/maillog when you attempt to `telnet localhost 25` from the server?

Comment: no messages there, but interestingly enough, telnet localhost 25 works fine while telnet mail.myserver.com 25 (also sent on the server of course) results in the 'connection refused' error.

Comment: @richey Your case is really abnormal... If firewall is OK, SELinux is OK, DNS is OK and the output of `netstat -an | grep 25` still shows that Postfix listens the wildcard address, the connection shall succeed. Could you verify if output of `ip addr show` displays the IP address that `telnet mail.myserver.com` tries to connect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that mail.myserver.com is both the SMTP server and the webserver running phpmailer, if not than this is not your issue.

It sounds like your SMTP server isn't listening on localhost but only on it's network IP. If so you need to configure your MTA to listen on localhost in addition to it's external interface. This is going to be different depending on your MTA.

For postfix (the default MTA for CentOS7) in main.cf set something like this:

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

or if you don't want to listen on all interfaces

```
inet_interfaces = 1.2.3.4, 127.0.0.1, [::1]
```

and restart postfix.

Comment: hmmm... strangely enough, this statement is there. I've added the netstat output to the OP if that helps... and yes, webserver=smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use CentOS 7. Perhaps SELinux is preventing phpmailer from sending mail, as it blocks `httpd` outgoing connections by default.

I suggest enabling the `httpd_can_network_connect` boolean:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

This will allow all outgoing connections made by `httpd`. Unfortunately, I didn't acquire sufficient SELinux knowledge, so I'm not able to answer how to limit allowed outgoing connections to SMTP ports only (25, 465 and 587).

If the webserver and the mailserver are the same machine, you can configure PHPMailer to send messages using the local `sendmail` binary and enable the `httpd_can_sendmail` boolean instead:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1
```

Comment: SELinux is not enabled, the above command confirmed that (I wanted to make sure just in case.. ;))